# Unable to bootstrap (cloud type: localhost) - Error when installing Kuberneters cluster locally with LXD/Conjure-up

Tags: kubernetes, lxd

Using Ubuntu 18.04.

I am trying to install a kubernetes cluster on my local machine (localhost) using this guide (LXD + conjure-up kubernetes):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/local/#before-you-begin

When I run:

```
conjure-up kubernetes
```

I select the following installation:

[image]

and select `localhost` for "Choose a cloud" and use the defaults for the rest of the install wizard. It then starts to install and after 30-40 minutes it completes with this error:

[image]

Here is the log:
https://pastebin.com/raw/re1UvrUU

Where one error says:

```
2018-07-25 20:09:38,125 [ERROR] conjure-up/canonical-kubernetes - events.py:161 - Unhandled exception in <Task finished coro=<BaseBootstrapController.run() done, defined at /snap/conjure-up/1015/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/juju/bootstrap/common.py:15> exception=BootstrapError('Unable to bootstrap (cloud type: localhost)',)>
```

but that does not really help much.

Any suggestion to why the install wizard/conjure-up fails?

Also based on this post:

https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/1308

I have tried to first disable firewall:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

and then re-run installation/conjure install wizard. But I get the same error.

Some more details on how I installed and configured LXD/conjure-up below:

```
$ snap install lxd
lxd 3.2 from 'canonical' installed
$ /snap/bin/lxd init
Would you like to use LXD clustering? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Do you want to configure a new storage pool? (yes/no) [default=yes]: 
Name of the new storage pool [default=default]: 
Name of the storage backend to use (btrfs, ceph, dir, lvm) [default=btrfs]: 
Create a new BTRFS pool? (yes/no) [default=yes]: 
Would you like to use an existing block device? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Size in GB of the new loop device (1GB minimum) [default=26GB]: 
Would you like to connect to a MAAS server? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Would you like to create a new local network bridge? (yes/no) [default=yes]: 
What should the new bridge be called? [default=lxdbr0]: 
What IPv4 address should be used? (CIDR subnet notation, “auto” or “none”) [default=auto]: 
What IPv6 address should be used? (CIDR subnet notation, “auto” or “none”) [default=auto]: 
Would you like LXD to be available over the network? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Would you like stale cached images to be updated automatically? (yes/no) [default=yes] 
Would you like a YAML "lxd init" preseed to be printed? (yes/no) [default=no]:
```

Configured group membership:

```
sudo usermod -a -G lxd $USER
newgrp lxd
```

Next installed:

```
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
```

And then ran installation:

```
conjure-up kubernetes
```

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way or are you still stuck with that `localhost` problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce your exact problem but i got `conjure-up` + `lxd` installed and in the end Kubernetes on my newly installed VirtualBox Ubuntu 18.04 (Desktop) VM. Hopefully this answer could help you somehow!

I looked through the kubernetes.io documentation page and that one lacked tiny bits of information, it does mention `lxd` but not the part with `lxd init` which i assume you picked up in the [conjure-up user manual](https://docs.conjure-up.io/stable/en/user-manual).

So with that said, i followed the `conjure-up` user manual with some minor changes on the way. I'm assuming that it's OK for you to use the edge version of `conjure-up`, i started off with the stable one but changed to edge when testing different combinations.

Also please ensure that you have the recommended resources available stated by the [user manual](https://docs.conjure-up.io/stable/en/user-manual), `conjure-up` and the *Canoncial Distribution of Kubernetes* launches a number of containers for you. You might not need 3 x *etcd*, 3 x *worker* nodes and 2 x *Master*, and if you don't just tune the number of containers down in the `conjure-up` wizard.

These are the steps i performed (as my local user):

1. Make sure your Ubuntu box are updated: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
2. Install `conjure-up` by running: `sudo snap install conjure-up --classic --edge`
3. Install `lxd` by running: `sudo snap install lxd`
4. With `lxd` comes the client part which is `lxc`, if you run e.g. `lxc list` you should get an empty table (no containers started yet). I got an permission error at this time, i ran the following: `sudo chown -R lxd:lxd /var/snap/lxd/` to change owner and group of the `lxd` directory containing the socket you'll be communicating with using `lxc`.
5. Add your user to the `lxd`group: `sudo usermod -a -G lxd $USER && newgrp lxd`, log off and on to make this permanent and not only active in your current shell.
6. Now create a `lxd` bridge manually with the following command: `lxc network create lxdbr1 ipv4.address=auto ipv4.nat=true ipv6.address=none ipv6.nat=false`
7. Now let's run the init part of `lxd` with `lxd init`. Remember to answer `no` when being asked to *create a new local network bridge?*, in the next prompt provide your newly created network bridge instead (`lxdbr1`). The rest of the answers to the questions can be left as default.
8. Now continue with running `conjure-up kubernetes` and choose `localhost` as your type. For me the `localhost` choice was greyed out from the beginning, it worked when i created the network bridge manually and not via the `lxd init` step.
9. Skip the additional components you can install like Rancher, Prometheus etc.
10. Choose your new network bridge and the default storage pool, proceed to the next step.
11. In the next step customize your Kubernetes cluster if needed and then hit Deploy. And now you wait!

You can always troubleshoot and list all containers created with the `lxc` tool. If you've ever used Docker the `lxc` tool feels a lot like the `docker` client.

And finally some thoughts and observations, there's *a lot* of moving parts to `conjure-up` as you might have seen. It's actually described as: *conjure-up is a thin layer spanning a few different underlying technologies - Juju, MAAS and LXD.*

For reference, i ended up having the following versions installed:

- `lxd` version 3.3
- `conjure-up` version 2.6.1